# Create table of specified column and rows in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery, I want to create table with specific number of rows and columns in jQuery.

Here is what I tried this creates table with specific number of rows but it doesn't create table of specific number of columns

```js
function constructTable () {
  let table = $('<table>').first().prepend('<caption><b> Borrow </b></caption>');
  let row;
  let cell1;
  let cell2;
  table.attr({"id":"burrow"});

  for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    row = $('<tr>');
    table.append(row);
   
  }
  
   for ( i = 0 ; i < 4; i++ ) {
    cell1 = $('<td>').text('cell ' + i);
    row.append(cell1);
  }

  
    $("#borrowLicensediv").append(table);
    document.getElementById('borrowLicensediv').style.display = ''; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
  
</head>
<body onload="constructTable ()" style="background: white;">
    <div id="borrowLicensediv" style="display: none; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:25px; margin-left:20px; margin-right:37px;"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to append the cells to each row as you make the row (put the cell loop inside the row loop (using a different var, not `i`))

Comment: Thanks that works

Comment: @freedomn-m If you make this an answer I will up it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you append rows to the table these must first have cells otherwise you're going to have empty rows in your table with no columns. Leaving jQuery aside for a moment, the general problem is:

1. Build a row
2. Append it to the table
3. Repeat 1 and 2 for all rows to add

Step (1) implies that you first create the cells you want in the row and add them to the row. This means you're going to have nested loops (whereas in your example they're inline).

You need something more like

```
for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    var row = "<tr>";
    for ( j = 0 ; j < 4; j++ ) {
        var value = "cell " + i + "," + j;
        var td = "<td>" + value + "</td>";
        row += td;
    }
    row += "</tr>";
    table.append(row);
}
```

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment - you need a different var for the inner loop - your code will not do what you think/want it to do

Comment: @freedomn correct, thanks for spotting the copy paste error on a previous version of this answer. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the TDs to the last Row because your cell loop is outside of the Row loop. We need to move the loop inside and fix the iterator variable, like this:

```
for(var r=0; r < 3; r++) {
   row = $('<tr>');

   for ( var c = 0 ; c < 4; c++ ) {
      cell = $('<td>').text('cell ' + r+c);
      row.append(cell);
   }
   table.append(row);   
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to close the `<tr>`?

Comment: Not needed `$("<tr>")` creates a node, not html

Comment: @freedomn-m I swear - It's like a day in college around here sometimes. lol Thanks for the information.